# Get notified when a third party app is launched for the first time

Tags: android

I want to get notified when 3rd party apps are opened by the user for the first time.

My app is a system app, so I can request system permissions.

I know I can do this by polling data such as the app's cache and seeing that it is larger than 0, but is there some other way to do that without polling? (for example, via BroadcastReceiver)

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you don't get any broadcast when you launch any application for the first time.

However you can check for Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY which will be set if the application has been launched from history. This will not fully solve your problem but will be just a case to check if in future you find a way to detect first application launch.